# plpgsql: syntax error at or near ";" LINE 66:END;

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

When I was trying to create this function in the Postgres server, it gave me this weird error:

> Syntax error at or near ";"
>      LINE 67: END;

Below is the code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "AGMI".make_process_detail(numeric,numeric)
    RETURNS text AS
    $BODY$

    DECLARE

    i_prog_ver_id            ALIAS FOR $1;
    i_priorityMfr_checker    ALIAS FOR $2;
    i_success                text;
    i_error_message          text;
    v_rankset_Rec            record;
    v_counter                integer;

    BEGIN 

          v_counter = 304;

          DELETE FROM "AGMI"."PROCESSING_DETAIL"
          WHERE "PROG_VER_ID" = i_prog_ver_id;

          INSERT INTO "AGMI"."PROCESSING_DETAIL"("PROG_VER_ID", "RANK_SET_CODE", "PROCESS", "RUN_NUMBER", "FLAG", "START_TIME", "WHEN_DONE", "TIME_TAKEN", "PASS_NUMBER") 
          VALUES (i_prog_ver_id,0,'PMODULE',301,0,Null,Null,Null,0);

          IF i_priorityMfr_checker = 1 THEN
             INSERT INTO "AGMI"."PROCESSING_DETAIL"("PROG_VER_ID", "RANK_SET_CODE", "PROCESS", "RUN_NUMBER", "FLAG", "START_TIME", "WHEN_DONE", "TIME_TAKEN", "PASS_NUMBER") 
             VALUES (i_prog_ver_id,0,'PRIORITIESMFR',302,0,Null,Null,Null,0);
          ELSE IF i_priorityMfr_checker = 0 THEN
             INSERT INTO "AGMI"."PROCESSING_DETAIL"("PROG_VER_ID", "RANK_SET_CODE", "PROCESS", "RUN_NUMBER", "FLAG", "START_TIME", "WHEN_DONE", "TIME_TAKEN", "PASS_NUMBER") 
             VALUES (i_prog_ver_id,0,'PRIORITIES',302,0,Null,Null,Null,0);
          ELSE
             i_error_message := "Invalid input for 2nd entry";
             RETURN i_error_message;
          END IF;

          INSERT INTO "AGMI"."PROCESSING_DETAIL"("PROG_VER_ID", "RANK_SET_CODE", "PROCESS", "RUN_NUMBER", "FLAG", "START_TIME", "WHEN_DONE", "TIME_TAKEN", "PASS_NUMBER") 
          VALUES (i_prog_ver_id,0,'FMODULE',303,0,Null,Null,Null,0);

          FOR v_rankset_Rec IN
                SELECT distinct "RANK_SET_CODE"
                FROM "AGMI"."RANKSET"
                WHERE "PROG_VER_ID" = i_prog_ver_id
                ORDER BY "RANK_SET_CODE"

                LOOP

           INSERT INTO "AGMI"."PROCESSING_DETAIL"("PROG_VER_ID", "RANK_SET_CODE", "PROCESS", "RUN_NUMBER", "FLAG", "START_TIME", "WHEN_DONE", "TIME_TAKEN", "PASS_NUMBER") 
           VALUES (i_prog_ver_id,v_rankset_Rec."RANK_SET_CODE",'FRANKSET',v_counter,0,Null,Null,Null,0);

           v_counter = v_counter+1;

           INSERT INTO "AGMI"."PROCESSING_DETAIL"("PROG_VER_ID", "RANK_SET_CODE", "PROCESS", "RUN_NUMBER", "FLAG", "START_TIME", "WHEN_DONE", "TIME_TAKEN", "PASS_NUMBER") 
           VALUES (i_prog_ver_id,v_rankset_Rec."RANK_SET_CODE",'NF',v_counter,0,Null,Null,Null,0);

           v_counter = v_counter+1;

           INSERT INTO "AGMI"."PROCESSING_DETAIL"("PROG_VER_ID", "RANK_SET_CODE", "PROCESS", "RUN_NUMBER", "FLAG", "START_TIME", "WHEN_DONE", "TIME_TAKEN", "PASS_NUMBER") 
           VALUES (i_prog_ver_id,v_rankset_Rec."RANK_SET_CODE",'SAT',v_counter,0,Null,Null,Null,0);

           v_counter = v_counter+1;

               END LOOP;

          i_success := 'Success';
          RETURN i_success;
    END; 
    $BODY$
       LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
    ALTER FUNCTION "AGMI".make_process_detail(numeric,numeric) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Updates: The complete function is included now.

Any idea why that is the error at the last row?

Comment: I don't know postgres, but what happens if you omit the trailing semicolon?

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I do have used the create function statement, so that wont be the problem. The error message were pointing at the next row of END;

Comment: I couldn't find anything weird here, cause I always use END as my last statement to END the block. And @Kay, i did try to omit the trailing semicolon, it showed me the same error. Anyone else knows what is going on here?

Comment: You are missing the closing `$body$` tag and the `language` specification

Comment: I did include them, still showed me the same error. Any other idea, no_name horse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ELSE IF i_priorityMfr_checker = 0 THEN
```

needs to be

```
ELSIF i_priorityMfr_checker = 0 THEN
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much, no_name horse:-)

Answer (score 0):

`ELSEIF` also works (with the 'E' in the middle).